# Error al configurar PHP 7 para conexion con SQL Server

Tags: php, sql

tengo un problema al ejecutar un archivo BAT, que adentro del mismo ejecuto un archivo PHP.

eso esta dentro del bat.

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.5\php-cgi.exe -f 
C:\wamp64\www\SCC\database\ingresos.php>nul
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con toda esa información está bastante difícil saber qué origina tu problema. No mencionas si tienes cargada la extensión o la vas a cargar, si ya instalaste los vc redistribuibles necesarios para wamp... No he trabajado con sqlserver pero a ver si esto te sirve: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/137, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068570/php-7-on-iis-call-user-function-could-not-be-located

Comment: hola buenas, si tengo las extensiones instaladas y también instale el vc